# Applying all jquery ui-interaction-states to all jquery ui-widget-content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When any item of class `ui-widget-content` experiences a hover, I want class `ui-state-hover` to be applied (and subsequently removed). The `ui-state-default` is applied by default, and so on for `focus` and `active`.

Am I missing an obvious part of jquery/jquery-ui, or do we have to write our own (admittedly rather simple) function for this?

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply classes manually yourself, try :

```
$(".ui-state-default").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
});
```

**edit**
An element could not have `ui-widget-content` and `ui-state-default` classes together.